# How can I pull a file that was added directly on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I updated a `README.md` file on GitHub.

How can I to pull it to my local Git repository?

Comment: `git pull` will do it.

Comment: There's no difference between files added or edited using GitHub's web UI and ones edited more traditionally. The web UI generates new Git commits in the GitHub repository.